# Check if one or more items of a list are in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I am currently cleaning up my Django code and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution for a problem I am solving rather clumsily at the moment.

I have 5 strings, `address_1` to `address_5`, and I would like to check if they any of them is a key in a dictionary called `result`, in which case the variable `contained` should be set to True. Currently, I am checking them separately (`if address_1 in result: contained = True, if address_2...`, but I there is a more elegant way that doesn't take 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression:

```
list_of_keys = ["address_1", "address_2", ...]

if any(k in result for k in list_of_keys):
    ...
```